# sudo apt-get update error message 16.04

Tags: updates

I'm running `sudo apt-get update` to update a new install on Ubuntu 16.04.2 64 bit. I get the following error message:

```
The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried using the apt-cdrom command to mount the cdrom but it seems to not work, I think i'm typing it in wrong as i am new to linux and have only been using it for a few weeks.I try to type in commands and it comes back as command cannot be found.the apt-cdrom has great info on how to probably solve this problem but I'm not sure how to use it or how to properly type the commands in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the installer CD loaded? It appears your `/etc/apt/sources.list` might think you do, and hence the angry errors.

What does the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` show you? In particular, is the line that starts with `deb cdrom` commented out (has a # prepended to it)? If not, it should be (assuming you don't have the CD loaded).

And remember that any changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list` requires a refresh (`sudo apt-get update`).

More details about managing Ubuntu repositories here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: I just reinstalled OS with a fresh burned dvd downloaded from Ubuntu and it seems to have solved the problem.I downloaded the origonal from bittorrent and must have not downloaded properly.But i have a new issue now the cat /etc/apt/sources.list says the distro is old and needs to be upgraded. also says  N.B software is entireley unsupported.

Comment: I also didn't have the disk in the pc.The computer seemed to work fine i just couldnt update anything